# Что такое localeCode?

Tags: python, парсер, requests

Есть сайт https://www.revolut.com/ru-EE/currency-converter/

В DevTools во вкладке network он отправляет запросы.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Причем если переходить по ссылке запроса в браузере, виден ответ. А если пробовать то же самое через postman, то не работает. Не знаете, что может быть не так?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуй убрать лишний localeCode из запроса. Он в postman дважды указан

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно добавить в headers -> **accept-language** **ru**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, помогло